# Why Oracle 19c got timezone version file timezlrg_40.dat

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I am a newbie in Oracle database.

My team setup 2 servers which use Oracle 19c, but timezone file version is different. First server is timezlrg_32.dat, another is timezlrg_40.dat.
Both 2 servers use version: Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production Version 19.18.0.0.0

- DB server 1:

select * from v$timezone_file;

| FILENAME | VERSION | CON_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| timezlrg_32.dat | 32 | 0 |

- DB server 2:

| FILENAME | VERSION | CON_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| timezlrg_40.dat | 40 | 0 |

My questions are:

1. Why they have different timezone file version?
2. I'm using oracle client (instantclient_19_8 => I think it locate to timezlrg_32.dat), so I need to downgrade DB server 2: timezlrg_40.dat => timezlrg_32.dat. How to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The database does not automatically get a new timezone file, so someone has most probably downloaded that timezone file and applied it via the usual process (DBMS_DST), or perhaps the database was created from scratch with the new file already in place.

In general, its better to be a newer timezone file than an old one, so I'd recommend settling on v40.

More details on obtaining the files and applying them can be found at MOS note Doc ID 412160.1